# Erro: Coleção foi modificada; talvez a operação de enumeração não seja executada

Tags: c#, array, .net, foreach

Estou com um problema ao utilizar o `foreach` para percorrer um *array* de *strings*.

Esse componente é um botão de procura para selecionar arquivos, ele seleciona e grava o endereço do arquivo em um *array* de *strings*, eu criei um laço de repetição para verificar se o mesmo arquivo foi selecionado duas vezes, mas a segunda execução do *loop* resulta em uma exceção.

Como a exceção é gerada:

1. Seleciono dois arquivos, eles são armazenados no *array* sem problemas.
2. Seleciono novamente os mesmos dois arquivos, para testar o método.
3. A primeira verificação é feita com sucesso, o programa reconhece que o arquivo já está na lista e não o adiciona.
4. Ao verificar o segundo arquivo a exceção é gerada.

[image]

```
    List<string> ListPath = new List<string>(); // Array
    string File; // Arquivo

    private void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog AbrirArquivo = new OpenFileDialog(); //Instância
        AbrirArquivo.Multiselect = true; // habilita a multseleção de arquivos
        if (AbrirArquivo.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) // ao pressionar ok
        {
            foreach (var File in AbrirArquivo.FileNames) // para cada arquivo no array
            {
                if(ListPath.Count == 0) // se a lista for vazia
                {
                    ListPath.Add(File); //adiciona o primeiro elemento
                }
                else // se não for vazia, agora ele verifica se já existe
                {
                    foreach(var item in ListPath) //Onde ocorre a Exception 
                    {
                        if(item == File) //se o item da lista for igual ao caminho do arquivo
                        {
                            continue; // pula para o próximo e não adiciona na lista
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ListPath.Add(File); // se não, adiciona.
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        PathText.Text = (ListPath.Count + " Arquivos selecionados"); 
// mostra em um textBox quantos arquivos foram selecionados.
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Por que não usa o LINQ que é muito mais fácil e evita esses erros?

```
listPath.AddRange(AbrirArquivo.FileNames.Distinct().ToList());
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/AddListDistinct.cs).

Comment: Super útil, não conhecia.